# Determining local geodatabase release version with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, esri-geodatabase, file-geodatabase, personal-geodatabase

Can anyone get the release version of a ESRI local geodatabase, ***using arcpy***? I should be simple, and yet...

I use the "Describe" function on both personal and file geodatabases, and need to retrieve the workspace properties "release" or "currentRelease" - either would do: I want to pinpoint databases that need upgrading (this project is run in ArcGIS 10.0, I am looking for 9.x databases.)

I based the code below on the properties exposed in the ESRI help ([here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000037000000)):

```
    import arcpy, os, sys

    data = r"C:\NEW_GDB.gdb"
    desc_gdb = arcpy.Describe(data)

    if hasattr(desc_gdb,"workspaceType"):
        print desc_gdb.workspaceType
        print desc_gdb.workspaceFactoryProgID
    else:
        print "no 'workspaceType' property"

    if hasattr(desc_gdb, "release"):
        print desc_gdb.release
    else:
        print "\nno 'release' property"

    if hasattr(desc_gdb, "currentRelease"):
        print desc_gdb.currentRelease
    else:
        print "no 'currentRelease' property"
```

And here is the result I get:

```
    >>> 
    LocalDatabase
    esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory.1

    no 'release' property
    no 'currentRelease' property
    >>>
```

Comment: The `release` and `currentRelease` properties weren't available until 10.1. So, if you're using 10.0, you won't have access to those properties. It you look at the documentation you posted, they aren't listed.

Comment: @ian: thanks for this, I had not noticed...It explains a lot of the difficulties I came accross!... Apologies everyone! (sheepish)

Comment: @ian...Well that explains a lot!  Good catch!

Comment: look at [this for release](http://pro.arcgis.com/fr/pro-app/arcpy/functions/workspace-properties.htm). It is same for gdb system (*.mdb and *.gdb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is strange, your code should work.  I can get this info just like you tried:

```
>>> gdb = r'E:\HamiltonCo\Soil_Library\AgLand_Adjustment\CSR_AgLand.gdb'
>>> desc = arcpy.Describe(gdb)
>>> desc.release
u'3,0,0'
>>> desc.currentRelease
True
>>>
```

If you are still having issues here, there is another Python solution, but it does not use arcpy.  Instead, it uses ArcObjects and the [comtypes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/comtypes) module.  You would also need to download the [snippets module](http://www.pierssen.com/arcgis10/upload/python/snippets102.py).

You can then run this function:

```
def CheckGDBRelease(sPath):
    """open file GDB"""
    InitStandalone()
    import comtypes.gen.esriGeoDatabase as esriGeoDatabase
    import comtypes.gen.esriDataSourcesGDB as esriDataSourcesGDB

    pWSF = NewObj(esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory, \
                  esriGeoDatabase.IWorkspaceFactory)
    pWS = pWSF.OpenFromFile(sPath, 0)
    pGDBRelease = CType(pWS, esriGeoDatabase.IGeodatabaseRelease2)
    return pGDBRelease.CurrentRelease, pGDBRelease.MajorVersion, pGDBRelease.MinorVersion

tup = CheckGDBRelease(r'E:\HamiltonCo\Soil_Library\AgLand_Adjustment\CSR_AgLand.gdb')
print tup
```

which printed:

```
>>> 
<POINTER(IApplication) ptr=0xf585994 at 87baee0>
(True, 3, 0)
>>>
```

This option may be more trouble than its worth though when your arcpy solution ***should*** be working

EDIT:

I have made many modifications to the snippets module with more helper functions.  Here is my complete code if you just want to use that instead:

```
#Most of this code adopted and modified from:
#
#    https://bitbucket.org/maphew/canvec/src/eaf2678de06f/Canvec/Scripts/parco.py
#
# For Bolton & Menk, Inc. use
#
# Snippets.py
# ************************************************
# Updated for ArcGIS 10.2
# ************************************************
# Requires installation of the comtypes package
# Available at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/comtypes/
# Once comtypes is installed, the following modifications
# need to be made for compatibility with ArcGIS 10.2:
# 1) Delete automation.pyc, automation.pyo, safearray.pyc, safearray.pyo
# 2) Edit automation.py
# 3) Add the following entry to the _ctype_to_vartype dictionary (line 794):
#    POINTER(BSTR): VT_BYREF|VT_BSTR,
# ************************************************
# Most of this code adopted and modified from:
#   https://bitbucket.org/maphew/canvec/src/eaf2678de06f/Canvec/Scripts/parco.py

# make sure it is being ran in 32 bit
import struct
if struct.calcsize('P') * 8 != 32:
    raise ImportError('Must use ArcObjects in 32 bit!')
import os
import glob

ACCESS_MODE = {
                0: 'unknown',
                2: 'write',
                4: 'read only',
                6: 'read/write'
              }

def load_mod(filterer=None):
    '''loads a list of all modules (*.olb files)

    Optional:
    filterer -- wildcard to search by.  If want to find all modules that start
        with "G", simply use "g" for the filterer
    '''
    olb = '*.olb'
    if filterer:
        olb = 'esri{0}*.olb'.format(filterer)
    mods = glob.glob(os.path.join(GetLibPath(), olb))
    if mods:
        all_mods = dict((i,os.path.basename(m)) for i,m in enumerate(mods))
        for k,v in sorted(all_mods.iteritems()):
            print '{0}: {1}'.format(k,v)
        return getModule(all_mods[input('\nChoose number for module\n')])
    print 'Did not find any modules!'
    return None

def load_all():
    '''loads all object libraries'''
    from comtypes.client import GetModule
    mods = glob.glob(os.path.join(GetLibPath(), '*.olb'))
    for mod in mods:
        GetModule(mod)
    return

def InstallInfo():
    """Gets ArcGIS Install Info"""
    # Get ArcObjects version
    import comtypes
    from comtypes.client import GetModule
    g = comtypes.GUID("{6FCCEDE0-179D-4D12-B586-58C88D26CA78}")
    GetModule((g, 1, 0))
    import comtypes.gen.ArcGISVersionLib as esriVersion
    pVM = NewObj(esriVersion.VersionManager, esriVersion.IArcGISVersion)
    return pVM.GetVersions().Next()

def GetLibPath():
    '''Reference to com directory which houses ArcObjects
    Ojbect Libraries (*.OLB)'''
    return os.path.join(InstallInfo()[2], 'com')

def GetVersion():
    """returns ArcGIS Version"""
    return InstallInfo()[1]

def getModule(sModuleName):
    ''' loads the object library by name'''
    from comtypes.client import GetModule
    olb = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(GetLibPath(), sModuleName))
    return GetModule(olb)

def GetStandaloneModules():
    """Import commonly used ArcGIS libraries for standalone scripts"""
    getModule("esriSystem.olb")
    getModule("esriGeometry.olb")
    getModule("esriCarto.olb")
    getModule("esriDisplay.olb")
    getModule("esriGeoDatabase.olb")
    getModule("esriDataSourcesGDB.olb")
    getModule("esriDataSourcesFile.olb")
    getModule("esriOutput.olb")

def GetDesktopModules():
    """Import basic ArcGIS Desktop libraries"""
    getModule("esriFramework.olb")
    getModule("esriArcMapUI.olb")
    getModule("esriArcCatalogUI.olb")

#**** Helper Functions ****

def GetCurrentApp():
    """Returns the Application if the script is being run from
    within the application boundary of an ArcGIS application"""
    import comtypes.gen.esriFramework as esriFramework
    return NewObj(esriFramework.AppRef, esriFramework.IApplication)

def GetApp(app="ArcMap"):
    InitStandalone()
    """app must be 'ArcMap' (default) or 'ArcCatalog'\n\
    Execute GetDesktopModules() first"""
    if not (app == "ArcMap" or app == "ArcCatalog"):
        print "app must be 'ArcMap' or 'ArcCatalog'"
        return None
    import comtypes.gen.esriFramework as esriFramework
    import comtypes.gen.esriArcMapUI as esriArcMapUI
    import comtypes.gen.esriCatalogUI as esriCatalogUI
    pAppROT = NewObj(esriFramework.AppROT, esriFramework.IAppROT)
    iCount = pAppROT.Count
    if iCount == 0:
        return None
    for i in range(iCount):
        pApp = pAppROT.Item(i)
        print pApp
        if app == "ArcCatalog":
            if CType(pApp, esriCatalogUI.IGxApplication):
                return pApp
            continue
        if CType(pApp, esriArcMapUI.IMxApplication):
            return pApp
    return None

def NewObj(COMClass, COMInterface):
    """Creates a new comtypes POINTER object where\n\
    MyClass is the class to be instantiated,\n\
    MyInterface is the interface to be assigned"""
    from comtypes.client import CreateObject
    try:
        ptr = CreateObject(COMClass, interface=COMInterface)
        return ptr
    except:
        return None

def CType(obj, interface):
    """Casts obj to interface and returns comtypes POINTER or None"""
    try:
        newobj = obj.QueryInterface(interface)
        return newobj
    except:
        return None

def CLSID(MyClass):
    """Return CLSID of MyClass as string

    CLSID is the GUID for the COM Class (CoClass) corresponding
    to instances of the object class
    """
    return str(MyClass._reg_clsid_)


#********* Stand alone ****

def InitStandalone():
    """Init standalone ArcGIS license"""
    # Set ArcObjects version
    import comtypes
    from comtypes.client import GetModule
    g = comtypes.GUID("{6FCCEDE0-179D-4D12-B586-58C88D26CA78}")
    GetModule((g, 1, 0))
    import comtypes.gen.ArcGISVersionLib as esriVersion
    import comtypes.gen.esriSystem as esriSystem
    pVM = NewObj(esriVersion.VersionManager, esriVersion.IArcGISVersion)
    # make sure version matches
    if not pVM.LoadVersion(esriVersion.esriArcGISDesktop, GetVersion()):
        return False
    # Get license
    pInit = NewObj(esriSystem.AoInitialize, esriSystem.IAoInitialize)
    ProductList = [esriSystem.esriLicenseProductCodeAdvanced, \
                   esriSystem.esriLicenseProductCodeStandard, \
                   esriSystem.esriLicenseProductCodeBasic]
    for eProduct in ProductList:
        licenseStatus = pInit.IsProductCodeAvailable(eProduct)
        if licenseStatus != esriSystem.esriLicenseAvailable:
            continue
        licenseStatus = pInit.Initialize(eProduct)
        return (licenseStatus == esriSystem.esriLicenseCheckedOut)
    return False

def check_extension(ext_code):
    """Determines whether or not an extension is checked out, returns True or False

    Required:
        ext_code -- extension code for license (int),
            for example, Spatial Analyst is code 10.

    Some common extension codes:
        6: Geostatistical Analyst
        8: Network Analyst
        9: 3D Analyst
       10: Spatial Analyst

    http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//004200000021000000
    """
    from comtypes.gen import esriSystem
    # now call AoInitialize
    pInit = NewObj(esriSystem.AoInitialize,
                    esriSystem.IAoInitialize)

    # check extension
    return pInit.IsExtensionCheckedOut(int(ext_code))

def mxd_version(mxd):
    #getModule('esriCarto')
    import comtypes.gen.esriCarto as esriCarto
    pMapDoc = NewObj(esriCarto.MapDocument, esriCarto.IMapDocument)
    pMapDoc.Open(mxd)
    ver_info = pMapDoc.GetVersionInfo()
    pMapDoc.Close()
    if not ver_info[0]:
        return '.'.join(map(str, ver_info[1:3]))
    print 'No Version info avaliable or the mxd was saved as a newer document'
    return None

def Msg(message="Hello world", title="ARDemo"):
    '''Opens a dialog box with OK button

    Required:
    message -- text for message box
    title -- title of message box
    '''
    from ctypes import c_int, WINFUNCTYPE, windll
    from ctypes.wintypes import HWND, LPCSTR, UINT
    prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(c_int, HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT)
    fn = prototype(("MessageBoxA", windll.user32))
    return fn(0, message, title, 0)

def create_mxd(mapDoc):
    getModule('esriCarto.olb')
    import comtypes.gen.esriCarto as esriCarto
    mxd = NewObj(esriCarto.MapDocument, esriCarto.IMapDocument)
    mxd.New(mapDoc)
    mxd.Close()
    return mapDoc

def ref_mxd(mxd_path):
    getModule('esriArcMapUI.olb')
    getModule('esriCarto.olb')
    import comtypes.gen.esriArcMapUI as esriArcMapUI
    import comtypes.gen.esriCarto as esriCarto

    # create mapDoc
    return NewObj(esriCarto.MapDocument, esriCarto.IMapDocument).Open(mxd_path)

def Standalone_OpenSDE():
    """open SDE database"""
    GetStandaloneModules()
    InitStandalone()
    import comtypes.gen.esriSystem as esriSystem
    import comtypes.gen.esriGeoDatabase as esriGeoDatabase
    import comtypes.gen.esriDataSourcesGDB as esriDataSourcesGDB

    pPropSet = NewObj(esriSystem.PropertySet, esriSystem.IPropertySet)
    pPropSet.SetProperty("SERVER", "sunprod1")
    pPropSet.SetProperty("USER", "/")
    pPropSet.SetProperty("INSTANCE", "sde:oracle10g:/;LOCAL=PRODUCTION_TUCSON")
    pPropSet.SetProperty("AUTHENTICATION_MODE", "OSA")
    pPropSet.SetProperty("VERSION", "SDE.DEFAULT")
    pWSF = NewObj(esriDataSourcesGDB.SdeWorkspaceFactory, \
                  esriGeoDatabase.IWorkspaceFactory)
    pWS = pWSF.Open(pPropSet, 0)
    pDS = CType(pWS, esriGeoDatabase.IDataset)
    print "Workspace name: " + pDS.BrowseName
    print "Workspace category: " + pDS.Category
    return pWS


def Standalone_OpenFileGDB(sPath):
    """open file GDB"""
    GetStandaloneModules()
    if not InitStandalone():
        print "We've got lumps of it 'round the back..."
        return
    import comtypes.gen.esriGeoDatabase as esriGeoDatabase
    import comtypes.gen.esriDataSourcesGDB as esriDataSourcesGDB

    pWSF = NewObj(esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory, \
                  esriGeoDatabase.IWorkspaceFactory)
    pWS = pWSF.OpenFromFile(sPath, 0)
    pDS = CType(pWS, esriGeoDatabase.IDataset)
    print "Workspace name: " + pDS.BrowseName
    print "Workspace category: " + pDS.Category
    return pWS

def CheckGDBRelease(sPath):
    """open file GDB"""
    InitStandalone()
    import comtypes.gen.esriGeoDatabase as esriGeoDatabase
    import comtypes.gen.esriDataSourcesGDB as esriDataSourcesGDB

    pWSF = NewObj(esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory, \
                  esriGeoDatabase.IWorkspaceFactory)
    pWS = pWSF.OpenFromFile(sPath, 0)
    pGDBRelease = CType(pWS, esriGeoDatabase.IGeodatabaseRelease2)
    return pGDBRelease.CurrentRelease, pGDBRelease.MajorVersion, pGDBRelease.MinorVersion

def OpenFeatureClass(sFileGDB, sFCName):
    InitStandalone()
    import comtypes.gen.esriGeoDatabase as esriGeoDatabase
    import comtypes.gen.esriDataSourcesGDB as esriDataSourcesGDB
    pWSF = NewObj(esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory, \
                  esriGeoDatabase.IWorkspaceFactory2)
    pWS = pWSF.OpenFromFile(sFileGDB, 0)
    pFWS = CType(pWS, esriGeoDatabase.IFeatureWorkspace)

    # determine if FC exists before attempting to open
    # http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriGeoDatabase/IWorkspace2_NameExists.htm
    #   5 = feature class datatype
    pWS2 = CType(pWS, esriGeoDatabase.IWorkspace2)
    if pWS2.NameExists(5, sFCName):
        pFC = pFWS.OpenFeatureClass(sFCName)
    else:
        pFC = None
        print '** %s not found' % sFCName

    return pFC

def getUnitSize(my_size, rounding=1):
    """will return a size in bytes to human readable format"""
    if not isinstance(my_size, (float, int, long)):
        my_size = sys.getsizeof(my_size)
    theSize = '0 KB'
    if my_size == 0:
        theSize = '0 KB'
    if my_size <= 1024:
        theSize = '1 KB'
    elif my_size > 1024 and my_size <= 1048576:
        theSize = '%s KB' %round(my_size/1024.0, rounding)
    elif my_size > 1048576 and my_size <= 1073741824:
        theSize = '%s MB' %round(my_size/1048576.0, rounding)
    elif my_size > 1073741824 and my_size <= 1099511627776:
        theSize = '%s GB' %round(my_size/1073741824.0, rounding)
    elif my_size >= 1099511627776:
        theSize = '%s TB' %round(my_size/1099511627776.0, rounding)
    else:
        # default return size in MB
        return '%s MB' %round(my_size/1048576.0, rounding)
    return theSize

def GetModifiedDate(fc, statType=2):
    """Gets information on feature class and returns a tuple of (mode, size, time)

    Required:
        fc -- feature class to check

    Optional:
        statType -- type of time info as shown below.  Default is 2
            0   Return the time last accessed.
            1   Return the time last created.
            2   Return the time last modified.
    modified from:
        https://geonet.esri.com/thread/74409
    """
    import datetime
    InitStandalone()
    import comtypes.gen.esriSystem as esriSystem
    import comtypes.gen.esriGeoDatabase as esriGeoDatabase
    import comtypes.gen.esriDataSourcesGDB as esriDataSourcesGDB

    # Open the FGDB
    gdb, tableName = os.path.split(fc)
    pWS = Standalone_OpenFileGDB(gdb)

    # Create empty Properties Set
    pPropSet = NewObj(esriSystem.PropertySet, esriSystem.IPropertySet)
    pPropSet.SetProperty("database", gdb)

    # Cast the FGDB as IFeatureWorkspace
    pFW = CType(pWS, esriGeoDatabase.IFeatureWorkspace)

    # Open the table
    pTab = pFW.OpenTable(tableName)

    # Cast the table as a IDatasetFileStat
    pDFS = CType(pTab, esriGeoDatabase.IDatasetFileStat)

    # Get the date modified
    mod = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(pDFS.StatTime(statType)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return (ACCESS_MODE[pDFS.StatMode], getUnitSize(pDFS.StatSize), mod)

#**** ArcMap ****

def MapRefresh(current=True):
    """refreshes ArcMap's TOC and active view"""
    from comtypes.gen import esriArcMapUI

    # reresh active view and TOC
    if current:
        pApp = GetCurrentApp()
    else:
        pApp = GetApp()
    pDoc = pApp.Document
    pMxDoc = CType(pDoc, esriArcMapUI.IMxDocument)
    pMxDoc.UpdateContents()
    pMxDoc.ActiveView.Refresh()
    del pApp, pMxDoc
    return

def ArcMap_GetSelectedGeometry(bStandalone=False):

    GetDesktopModules()
    if bStandalone:
        InitStandalone()
        pApp = GetApp()
    else:
        pApp = GetCurrentApp()
    if not pApp:
        print "We found this spoon, sir."
        return
    import comtypes.gen.esriFramework as esriFramework
    import comtypes.gen.esriArcMapUI as esriArcMapUI
    import comtypes.gen.esriSystem as esriSystem
    import comtypes.gen.esriCarto as esriCarto
    import comtypes.gen.esriGeoDatabase as esriGeoDatabase
    import comtypes.gen.esriGeometry as esriGeometry

    # Get selected feature geometry

    pDoc = pApp.Document
    pMxDoc = CType(pDoc, esriArcMapUI.IMxDocument)
    pMap = pMxDoc.FocusMap
    pFeatSel = pMap.FeatureSelection
    pEnumFeat = CType(pFeatSel, esriGeoDatabase.IEnumFeature)
    pEnumFeat.Reset()
    pFeat = pEnumFeat.Next()
    if not pFeat:
        print "No selection found."
        return
    pShape = pFeat.ShapeCopy
    eType = pShape.GeometryType
    if eType == esriGeometry.esriGeometryPoint:
        print "Geometry type = Point"
    elif eType == esriGeometry.esriGeometryPolyline:
        print "Geometry type = Line"
    elif eType == esriGeometry.esriGeometryPolygon:
        print "Geometry type = Poly"
    else:
        print "Geometry type = Other"
    return pShape

def ArcMap_GetEditWorkspace(bStandalone=False):

    GetDesktopModules()
    if bStandalone:
        InitStandalone()
        pApp = GetApp()
    else:
        pApp = GetCurrentApp()
    GetModule("esriEditor.olb")
    import comtypes.gen.esriSystem as esriSystem
    import comtypes.gen.esriEditor as esriEditor
    import comtypes.gen.esriGeoDatabase as esriGeoDatabase
    pID = NewObj(esriSystem.UID, esriSystem.IUID)
    pID.Value = CLSID(esriEditor.Editor)
    pExt = pApp.FindExtensionByCLSID(pID)
    pEditor = CType(pExt, esriEditor.IEditor)
    if pEditor.EditState == esriEditor.esriStateEditing:
        pWS = pEditor.EditWorkspace
        pDS = CType(pWS, esriGeoDatabase.IDataset)
        print "Workspace name: " + pDS.BrowseName
        print "Workspace category: " + pDS.Category
    return

def ArcMap_GetSelectedTable(bStandalone=False):

    GetDesktopModules()
    if bStandalone:
        InitStandalone()
        pApp = GetApp()
    else:
        pApp = GetCurrentApp()
    import comtypes.gen.esriFramework as esriFramework
    import comtypes.gen.esriArcMapUI as esriArcMapUI
    import comtypes.gen.esriGeoDatabase as esriGeoDatabase
    pDoc = pApp.Document
    pMxDoc = CType(pDoc, esriArcMapUI.IMxDocument)
    pUnk = pMxDoc.SelectedItem
    if not pUnk:
        print "Nothing selected."
        return
    pTable = CType(pUnk, esriGeoDatabase.ITable)
    if not pTable:
        print "No table selected."
        return
    pDS = CType(pTable, esriGeoDatabase.IDataset)
    print "Selected table: " + pDS.Name

#**** ArcCatalog ****

def ArcCatalog_GetSelectedTable(bStandalone=False):

    GetDesktopModules()
    if bStandalone:
        InitStandalone()
        pApp = GetApp("ArcCatalog")
    else:
        pApp = GetCurrentApp()
    import comtypes.gen.esriFramework as esriFramework
    import comtypes.gen.esriCatalogUI as esriCatalogUI
    import comtypes.gen.esriCatalog as esriCatalog
    import comtypes.gen.esriGeoDatabase as esriGeoDatabase
    pGxApp = CType(pApp, esriCatalogUI.IGxApplication)
    pGxObj = pGxApp.SelectedObject
    if not pGxObj:
        print "Nothing selected."
        return
    pGxDS = CType(pGxObj, esriCatalog.IGxDataset)
    if not pGxDS:
        print "No dataset selected."
        return
    eType = pGxDS.Type
    if not (eType == esriGeoDatabase.esriDTFeatureClass or eType == esriGeoDatabase.esriDTTable):
        print "No table selected."
        return
    pDS = pGxDS.Dataset
    pTable = CType(pDS, esriGeoDatabase.ITable)
    print "Selected table: " + pDS.Name

# **** custom helper functions ****

def iterLayers(pApp=GetApp()):
    """creates a generator for layers"""
    from comtypes.gen import esriArcMapUI, esriCarto
    pDoc = pApp.Document
    pMxDoc = CType(pDoc, esriArcMapUI.IMxDocument)
    pMap = pMxDoc.FocusMap
    pAV = CType(pMap, esriCarto.IActiveView)

    # reference layer
    for i in range(pMap.LayerCount):
        yield pMap.Layer(i)

def alter_alias(fc, f_dict):
    '''Change field names at the database level

    Required:
    fc -- feature class (must be in gdb)
    f_dict -- fields dictionary {field_alias : new_alias, ...}
    '''
    getModule('esriGeoDatabase.olb')
    getModule('esriDataSourcesGDB.olb')
    import comtypes.gen.esriGeoDatabase as esriGeoDatabase

    # get at fc properties
    pFC = OpenFeatureClass(*os.path.split(fc))

    # get at schema editing library
    pSE = CType(pFC, esriGeoDatabase.IClassSchemaEdit)

    # iterate through dict and update aliases
    for field, alias in f_dict.iteritems():
        try:
            pSE.AlterFieldAliasName(field, alias)
            print 'Changed field "{0}"\'s alias to: "{1}"'.format(field, alias)
        except:
            print 'Error changing field "{0}"\'s alias to: "{1}"'.format(field, alias)
    return

def alter_fieldName(fc, f_dict):
    '''Change field names at the database level

    Required:
    fc -- feature class (must be in gdb)
    f_dict -- fields dictionary {field_name : new_name, ...}
    '''
    import comtypes.gen.esriGeoDatabase as esriGeoDatabase

    # get at fc properties
    pFC = OpenFeatureClass(*os.path.split(fc))

    # get at schema editing library
    pSE = CType(pFC, esriGeoDatabase.IClassSchemaEdit4)

    # iterate through dict and update aliases
    for field, new_name in f_dict.iteritems():
        try:
            pSE.AlterFieldName(field, new_name)
            print 'Changed field "{0}"\'s name to: "{1}"'.format(field, new_name)
        except:
            print 'Error changing field "{0}"\'s name to: "{1}"'.format(field, new_name)
    return
```

You can use the `load_all()` function to load all ArcObjects libraries.  The kicker is you need to load the 'olb' libraries first.  So I would call this first so it will generate all the Python wrappers inside the `gen` folder in the comtypes package. Once it has generated all the wrappers, the function I posted (included in my full script) should work.

You can leave this as a single module, or I have formatted as a package (I have other modules inside too such as working with mapsurround elements):

```
arcobjects <- folder
  __init__.py <- this is the full script I posted.
```

EDIT 2:

I now see why the `InitStandalone()` is not working for you.  If your tag is correct and you are using ArcGIS 10.0, the product codes are different (i.e. `esriSystem.esriLicenseProductCodeAdvanced` is the equivalent of `esriSystem.esriLicensProductCodeArcInfo`).  Since you are using ArcGIS 10.0, replace the InitStandalone() function with this [10.0 code](http://www.pierssen.com/arcgis10/upload/python/snippets100.py):

```
def InitStandalone():
    """Init standalone ArcGIS license"""
    # Set ArcObjects version
    import comtypes
    from comtypes.client import GetModule
    g = comtypes.GUID("{6FCCEDE0-179D-4D12-B586-58C88D26CA78}")
    GetModule((g, 1, 0))
    import comtypes.gen.ArcGISVersionLib as esriVersion
    import comtypes.gen.esriSystem as esriSystem
    pVM = NewObj(esriVersion.VersionManager, esriVersion.IArcGISVersion)
    if not pVM.LoadVersion(esriVersion.esriArcGISDesktop, "10.0"):
        return False
    # Get license
    pInit = NewObj(esriSystem.AoInitialize, esriSystem.IAoInitialize)
    ProductList = [esriSystem.esriLicenseProductCodeArcInfo, \
                   esriSystem.esriLicenseProductCodeArcEditor, \
                   esriSystem.esriLicenseProductCodeArcView]
    for eProduct in ProductList:
        licenseStatus = pInit.IsProductCodeAvailable(eProduct)
        if licenseStatus != esriSystem.esriLicenseAvailable:
            continue
        licenseStatus = pInit.Initialize(eProduct)
        return (licenseStatus == esriSystem.esriLicenseCheckedOut)
    return False
```

Comment: Ah, right, I forgot you need to load the `.olb` files (ArcObjecs Object Library files).  I edited my post to demonstrate this.  I would use my full script instead and call `load_all()` to generate the necessary files first.

Comment: thanks @crmackey! I tried using the full script. I appended at the end the call to load_all(), and then the call to  
'tup = CheckGDBRelease(r"K:\Doss\X999999\x8320\NEW_GDB.gdb")'
'print tup'  .    Was this the way to use it? I am getting an error on the "InitStandalone()" function, but I do not have a standalone license, so this is probably normal. Apologies!!... :)

Comment: Can you edit your original question to show what error message you are getting from the `InitStandalone()`.  And you should have a stand alone license, it is simply an ArcGIS license.  The important piece is here: `pInit = NewObj(esriSystem.AoInitialize, esriSystem.IAoInitialize)`.  Note, in the `CheckGDBRelease()`, you could substitute the call to `InitStandalone` with `import arcpy`.  That would initialize an ArcGIS license for stand alone use.

Comment: Many thanks for your help and patience!! Yes, **replacing InitStandalone with import arcpy did the trick**. I cannot edit my previous comment any longer, the error I was getting on InitStandalone was:      'ProductList = [esriSystem.esriLicenseProductCodeAdvanced, \
AttributeError: "module" object has no attribute "esriLicenseProductCodeAdvanced"'.    [and Apologies for the poor formatting of the comments, all my attempts at using quotes of tags fail :( ]

Comment: Last note: the code works OK for file geodatabases. For Personal Geodatabases, I have a constant unspecified COM error: _CheckGDBRelease_
    _pWS = pWSF.OpenFromFile(sPath, 0)_
_COMError: (-2147467259, 'Erreur non sp\xe9cifi\xe9e', (None, None, None, 0, None))_

Comment: Yes, this will not work on a personal geodatabase, because it is calling `esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory`.  In order to open a personal gdb, you need to use the `esriDataSourcesGDB.AccessWorkspaceFactory` class and cast it to the same `esriGeoDatabase.IWorkspaceFactory` interface: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/AccessWorkspaceFactoryClass_Class/001m00000001000000/

Comment: Also, I think I know why `InitStandalone()` is failing for you.  See EDIT2 in my answer.

Comment: @ crmackey: Yesss!!! Your EDIT2 on InitStandalone AND your tip on the AccessWorkspaceFactory have sorted me out completely.  This is brilliant, thank you so much for helping out so thoroughly (and patiently)!!!